# NullPointerException instead of null (JVM Bug?)

Tags: java, lambda, jvm, ternary-operator

I found a strange behaviour in the current version of Java 8. In my opinion the following code should be fine, but the JVM throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
Supplier<Object> s = () -> false ? false : false ? false : null;
s.get(); // expected: null, actual: NullPointerException
```

It doesn't matter, what kind of lambda expression it is (same with `java.util.function.Function`) or what generic types are used. There can also be more meaningful expressions in place of `false ? :`. The example above is very short. Here's a more colorful example:

```
Function<String, Boolean> f = s -> s.equals("0") ? false : s.equals("1") ? true : null;
f.apply("0"); // false
f.apply("1"); // true
f.apply("2"); // expected: null, actual: NullPointerException
```

However these code pieces run fine:

```
Supplier<Object> s = () -> null;
s.get(); // null
```

and

```
Supplier<Object> s = () -> false ? false : null;
s.get(); // null
```

Or with function:

```
Function<String, Boolean> f = s -> {
    if (s.equals("0")) return false;
    else if (s.equals("1")) return true;
    else return null;
};
f.apply("0"); // false
f.apply("1"); // true
f.apply("2"); // null
```

I tested with two Java versions:

`~# java -version`

> openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b01)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b01, mixed mode)

`C:\>java -version`

> java version "1.8.0_51"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: How is this different from `Object a = false ? false : false ? false : null;` which also yields a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: It occurs in Java 7 and Java 8 (OpenJDK).

Comment: @bayou.io How so? Lambdas don't add anything. The "problem" is ternary expressions.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is the unboxing of `null` to a `boolean` value because of the binding/precedence in the use of the two `?:` operators. The duplicate post says as much (maybe not so much about the binding, but implies it). There's no need for 10 different posts about this. If you have a better duplicate, I'd be happy to reopen and we can reclose it as such. This question has been answered many times over.

Comment: @steffen - apparently there is unboxing somewhere. but it's unclear why; or whether it's legal or a bug. I bet even the language designer couldn't answer it off the top of their head. java8 really makes `?:` even more complicated. See my analysis [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/-ap9v5MDO_4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with lambda expressions; it is simply that the return type of the ternary operator in that case is `boolean`, so auto-unboxing will be used.

NPE is thrown here as well:

```
public class Main {

    private static Object method() {
        return false ? false : false ? false : null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(method());
    }
}
```

So, what exactly is happening here?

Firstly, 'embedded' expression (`false ? false : null`) is evaluated according to JLS [§15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> The conditional operator is syntactically right-associative (it groups
>   right-to-left). Thus, a?b:c?d:e?f:g means the same as
>   a?b:(c?d:(e?f:g)).

The type of the embedded expression is `Boolean` (boxed `boolean`), so that both `false` and `null` can fit into it.

Then the whole expression is:

```
false ? false : (Boolean expression)
```

Then, again according to JLS [§15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and
>   the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion
>   (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

So, the first argument is of primitive type `boolean` (`T` in the spec), the type of the other is the boxed `T` (`Boolean`), so the type of the entire expression is `boolean`.

Then, in runtime, the embedded expression evaluates to `null` which is auto-unboxed to `boolean`, causing the NPE.

Comment: well, OP's code is in java8, so we must consider target typing `Object`, and we must analyze whether it should affect operands; why unboxing is done instead of boxing.

Comment: Then why does `false ? false : false ? Boolean.FALSE : null;` still throw an NPE. The second operand of the nested expression is `Boolean`, so no boxing conversion will be applied (§5.1.7). The outer expression would be `false ? false : (Boolean expression)`. The next line in JLS §15.25 reads `If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the conditional expression is that reference type.` OK, but finally that would be equal to `false ? false : (Boolean) null`.

Comment: `false ? false : false ? Boolean.FALSE : null` is the same thing. The embedded ternary expression evaluates to `Boolean`, and the entire expression returns `boolean`, because it's the primitive type `T` quoted above.

Comment: Regarding the paragraph you quoted, there is no such an occurence in the expression, `false` is not reference type, and `(Boolean) null` is not null type.

Comment: The quoted JLS sentence applies to `false ? false : false ? Boolean.FALSE : null` (one of the 2,3 operarands is `null`, the other is reference type). Hence the type of the inner expression is that reference type (`Boolean`, no autoboxing). The whole expression therefore is `boolean ? boolean : Boolean`, which gives an NPE. But in regards to the original question, your explanation is perfect (+1), at least while bayou.io doesn't find Java 8 specifics.